# Unable to update variable product data in WooCommerce

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

I am trying to set my product price to some fixed amount , i tired to change in 
variable product ->variations -> set regular price

After clicking save changes the data is not saving at all , i am getting only loading image in screen , and its not ending at all !

please check this image

[image: editproductpage]

i am using WordPress version 4.9.8 , is it because of old version ?

here is my product page link 
[product page link](https://www.dandygas.com.au/product/steel-blue-adelaide-sports-lace-safety-cap)

Comment: Please check the browser console if any error happened. Also how many variations do you have for this product?

Comment: i have this error message in console 'VM21:1 POST https://www.dandygas.com.au/wp-admin/admin-ajax.php?_fs_blog_admin=true 500 (Internal Server Error)'

and i have 14 variations for this product

Comment: I suspect _fs_blog_admin is causing you issues.

Can you try disabling all  other plugins and see if this fixes the issue? 
If it does fix the issue, then try re-enabling your plugins one by one until the issue comes back. This procedure will help diagnose which plugin is causing the issue.

Comment: Yes you are right ! one of the SEO plugin was causing the problem ! now all fixed ! thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I suspect `_fs_blog_admin` is causing you issues. Can you try disabling all other plugins and see if this fixes the issue? If it does fix the issue, then try re-enabling your plugins one by one until the issue comes back. This procedure will help diagnose which plugin is causing the issue.